# What are the limitations of the bonding ritual performed by an eldritch knight?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, eldritch-knight

I was wondering what the bonding process looks like or if you can decide it yourself.
As an example: if the fighter goes into a museum or other public exhibit and sees a sword on display, can he then bond with it by walking around it and pretending to be interested in it for an hour and then make it appear in his hand when he is a safe distance away?

Comment: There is an implied question hidden in the text: **Is the EK bonding ritual inconspicuous enough to be disguised as loitering?** - but then we can take this implied question as part of the "limitations" the title refers to.

Comment: The implied question should be made explicit, for the same reason that, if you were trying this trick at the table, you'd want to tell the DM when you _start_ the ritual.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The bonding process requires you to be able to touch the weapon

The PHB (p. 75) says:

> The weapon must be within your reach throughout the ritual, at the conclusion of which you touch the weapon and forge the bond.

Using your example of trying to steal a sword from a museum or exhibit, you would need to touch the weapon at the end of the ritual, so the weapon must be available for you to touch (i.e. not behind glass or within a cage or something), but otherwise, it's up to your DM to decide what this ritual looks like (and therefore whether it's obvious to the sword's owner that you're up to something), since the rules do not elaborate on that narrative detail.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86886/discussion-on-answer-by-nathans-what-does-the-binding-ritual-look-like-when-perf).

Comment: @Mindwin I think this would be covered by "it's up to your DM to decide what this ritual looks like (and therefore whether it's obvious to the sword's owner that you're up to something), since the rules do not elaborate on that narrative detail." Without more to go on RAW, there's simply no way to determine this outside of "ask your DM".